Can we create the style with Curves for complete page?
while exporting the data to PDF we can use the background image as design for whole page which required border and specific page design but it seems its not good practice because image will slow down the export process and depending on number of pages the memory also is an issue.
Can we create the attached design in pure CSS? or is there some better way to resolve these type issues?
Tried with export to PDF as background Image which is too slow with the export. So need to achieve same design with the CSS


What method do you use to export to PDF? What is the size of your paper? Why not show us the code you created to do this with an image?

@KIKOSoftware yes its image currently as background while size of paper is A4 while for exporting, complete HTML page exported as PDF

@KJ Thank you for details and the shared example. The expectation almost same as you shared but without image. Yes Designer need to do work here for sure but question remains can we achieve the above design with CSS? I want to avoid the Image as page background as it still covers all the page. Only logo should be as image all other should be as Text. Can you please some website or tool which is helpful in case we can't achieve same with css so it can be the last option to utilize BG as Image

What CSS can be used depends on the method you use to export the HTML to PDF. You haven't told us, despite me clearly asking for it.

Dear @KIKOSoftware, I am using UltimatePDF Forge component of Outsystems, but I am
looking to change it and any PDF library in .net or simple HTML with CSS to generate the above design will be helpful. We can integrate  the out in Outsystems

Thank you for answering that question. I see that UltimatePDF Forge component of Outsystems is just a shell around Google's headless Chrome v123, so it should support most HTML/CSS features. It should even be able to replace your current image with an SVG image. I know, this isn't CSS, but it will do the job.

This is primarily a graphics PAGE design issue that has problems in web applications.
Document pages are fixed media they have a pre-set width and height for multi-page save or print. Whilst web "pages" are one single variable shape with dynamic width and heights.
Thus CSS is not really designed for page design, but we can work with some of its limitations, since it is highly variable, and here the dynamic HTML on the left can be forced to fit ONE page output.

I have not spent time on drawing a fixed head set of curves (though it is possible) since I suggest this is NOT the best approach.
You should be designing a page as lightweight scalable vectors as a background VECTOR image that can be a fixed size for output. Then fit the text and pixel images such as the logo overlaid on that.

